# Expectation of the maximum order statistic of Pareto distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, order-statistics

Suppose X follows the Pareto Type I given,

$$P(X>x) = \Bigl(\frac{\gamma}{x}\Bigl)^\alpha, \quad x\geq \gamma,\; \alpha>0.$$

Then,
\begin{align*}
P(X=x) &= \frac{d}{dx}P(X\leq x)\\
&= \frac{d}{dx}\biggl(1-\Bigl(\frac{\gamma}{x}\Bigl)^{\alpha}\biggl)\\
&= \frac{\alpha\gamma^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}, \quad x\geq \gamma,\; \alpha>0.
\end{align*}

Using the property of the order statistics,
\begin{align*}
f_{X_{(n)}}(x) &= nf(x)F(x)^{n-1}\\
&= n\cdot\frac{\alpha\gamma^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}\biggl(1-\Bigl(\frac{\gamma}{x}\Bigl)^{\alpha}\biggl)^{n-1}, \quad x \geq \gamma,\; \alpha>0.
\end{align*}

I'm trying to derive the expectation of the maximum order statistic, which is
\begin{align*}
E(X_{(n)}) &= \int_{\gamma}^\infty x\cdot n\cdot\frac{\alpha\gamma^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}}\biggl(1-\Bigl(\frac{\gamma}{x}\Bigl)^{\alpha}\biggl)^{n-1} dx\\
&= n\alpha \int_{\gamma}^{\infty} \Bigl(\frac{\gamma}{x}\Bigl)^{\alpha}\biggl(1-\Bigl(\frac{\gamma}{x}\Bigl)^{\alpha}\biggl)^{n-1} dx
\end{align*}

but do not know how to proceed from this step.
(also not sure is there any closed-form value for this expectation)

Comment: If $Y$ is a random variable that only takes positive values then:$$\mathbb EY=\int_0^{\infty}P(Y>x)dx$$Doesn't that help if you apply this on $Y=X_{(n)}$? Further if you take the derivative of CDF then this gives you the PDF and not $P(X=x)$ as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_{\gamma}^{\infty} \Bigl(\frac{\gamma}{x}\Bigl)^{\alpha}\biggl(1-\Bigl(\frac{\gamma}{x}\Bigl)^{\alpha}\biggl)^{n-1} dx$$

The antiderivative is given in terms of the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$-\frac{x }{\alpha -1}\left(\frac{\gamma }{x}\right)^{\alpha } \,
   _2F_1\left(1-n,\frac{\alpha -1}{\alpha };\frac{2\alpha
   -1}{\alpha };\left(\frac{\gamma }{x}\right)^{\alpha
   }\right)$$ Using the limits
$$\color{blue}{I=\frac{\gamma  }{\alpha  }\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(1-\frac{1}{\alpha }\right) \Gamma
   (n)} {\Gamma \left(n+1-\frac{1}{\alpha }\right) }}$$

**Edit**

Letting $x=\gamma \, t^{-1/a}$, you also have
$$I=\frac \gamma \alpha \int_0^1 t^{-1/a} (1-t)^{n-1}\,dt$$ The antiderivative is
$$\frac \gamma {\alpha-1} \,t^{\frac{\alpha -1}{\alpha }}\, _2F_1\left(1-n,\frac{\alpha -1}{\alpha };\frac{2\alpha-1}{\alpha};t\right)$$

Comment: Could you explain in more detail the process of obtaining the antiderivative?

Comment: @R.V. Please, visit first  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function

Comment: @AxelT. Answer edited ans result simplified. Remember that there is a bunch of inter relations for hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, the second integral is clearer! Note that is is the Beta function as well. You get that it converges for only some values of $\alpha$ which is expected for the Pareto distribution.

Comment: @AxelT. Yes, if is a beta function. May I confess that the last time I used a distribution function was probably 60+ years ago ? Cheers :-)